# phpMyAdmin: Date Fields Display as BLOB

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I am running phpMyAdmin version 4.4.4. When browsing a table, all of the DATETIME and DATE fields display as **[BLOB 19]**. I clicked on +Options above the table list, selected "Show BLOB contents" and clicked GO, but, all date fields still display as [BLOB 19].

I've tried this on three different Mac browsers -- Safari, Chrome and Firefox -- but none of them will display the actual date, just [BLOB 19].

How do I make PMA show the actual date instead of BLOB?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have since found the solution to this problem. phpMyAdmin was not using the mysqli extension. Once I added the mysqli extension to PHP, all of the date fields started displaying the date instead of BLOB.